# No sound when turning ignition unless wait 30min

Tags: electrical, toyota, starting, troubleshooting

I have Toyota Solara 2005. Today when I turn on ignition, no sound. No cranking noise.
But after like 30min, I can turn it on and engine started. I drove home and tried to turn again, dead. No sound.

So it’s no the battery because lights are on. Can starter be “flaky”? Or most likely ignition (something to do with electrical)?

Comment: Everything else is as normal, just the starter motor does nothing?  No clicks from the starter solenoid?

Comment: It very well could be the battery or a bad connection at the battery.  Just because the lights come on does not prove/indicate your battery is healthy.  Did you check battery voltage?  If not, I would recommend you start there and report back.